# MACOS terminal - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' when compiling

Tags: compilation, ethereum, solidity, nft, hardhat

Completely new to this stuff. Trying to deploy an NFT for my bachelor's thesis in a non-technical field.

I've been following this guide:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-an-nft/
And it's been going pretty well up until the point where I'm supposed to deploy the NFT and edit the HardHat config file to compile everything.

The guide has been using the "ropsten" network while I'm using rinkeby. Is that the problem?

This is my HardHat config file:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/MYURLCODE,
      accounts: [`0x${process.env.MYPRIVATEKEY}`],
    },
  },
};
```

And this is my error message:

```html
MYNAME@Ivans-MacBook-Pro ethereum % npx hardhat compile
An unexpected error occurred:

/Users/MYNAME/nft-project/ethereum/hardhat.config.js:10
      url: process.env.https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/MYURL,
                            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at importCsjOrEsModule (/Users/MYNAME/nft-project/ethereum/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/config/config-loading.ts:28:20)
    at loadConfigAndTasks (/Users/MYNAME/nft-project/ethereum/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/config/config-loading.ts:80:18)
```

Would be incredibly grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the snippet i guess this line `url: process.env.https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/MYURLCODE` should become:

```
url: `https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.MYURLCODE}`
```

assuming that your `MYURLCODE` env variable contains the correct value.